# Recyclerview scrollbar cliptoPadding false?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, padding

I have a recyclerview with padding top and bottom for 10dp.

And I add `clipToPadding=false` like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

I notice that my scrollbar will actually respect the top and bottom padding, and does not scroll the whole height.

Is there a way so that my scrollbar actually scrolls top and bottom completely?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to add `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` to your recyclerView.

ref - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarStyle

You can achieve similar scrollbar results with it.

[image: scrollbar outside overlay]

Answer (score -1):

The quickest fix for this would be to opt in for the new Fast scroll bars on the RecyclerView:

As per the docs version 26.0.0:

> New fastScrollEnabled boolean flag for RecyclerView. If enabled,
>   fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable, fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable,
>   fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable, and fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable
>   must be set.

So Setup two files:

`track_drawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/state_normal_track" />
</selector>
```

and `thumb_drawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/state_normal_scrollbar_thumb" />
</selector>
```

and here are the colors I used:

```
<!-- Fast Scroll track state colors -->
<color name="state_normal_track">#EEEEEE</color>

<!-- Scroll Bar thumb state colors -->
<color name="state_normal_scrollbar_thumb">#9E9E9E</color>
```

Finally on your RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/vertical_track_drawable"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/vertical_track_drawable"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/vertical_thumb_drawable"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/vertical_thumb_drawable" />
```

Good luck and Happy Coding!